# Swift 3 - Cannot change background color on my Cell.AccessoryView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get the background of my UITableViewCell's AccessoryView to be the same color as the rest of my cell, but I cannot get it work out. No matter what the AccessoryView background is always gray

My UITableView uses STATIC cells, so no data is loaded.

Here's my code:

```
// Table setup

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
        cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2250251152, green: 1, blue: 0.1816247099, alpha: 0.5082940925)
        cell?.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2250251152, green: 1, blue: 0.1816247099, alpha: 0.5082940925)
        (superView as! ProjectTestSelectViewController).updateProjectHandlerTests(cell!, didSelect: true)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.2)
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.2)
        cell?.accessoryType = .none
        (superView as! ProjectTestSelectViewController).updateProjectHandlerTests(cell!, didSelect: false)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.2)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.2)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        view.tintColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.8)
    }
```

Here's a screenshot

[image]

I've tried using the code below, but it does not effect the background color.

> cell?.accessoryView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

Comment: try `cell.accessoryView.tintColor = UIColor.clear`

Comment: @f_qi I tried and it did not work. I also tried it in combination with `cell?.accessoryView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear`

Comment: Where did you put the code in? Also,in `cellForRowAt indexPath:` try `cell.selectionStyle = .none`

Comment: I put the code inside the `didSelectRowAt indexPath:`. All of my cells are already set up to have `cell.selectionStyle = .none`

Comment: Could you post the code for `cellForRowAt indexPath:`?

Comment: Ah, I misread your comment. I don't have a `cellForRowAt indexPath:` because I didn't think I had any reason to call it with static cells. I don't know how to set up the `cellForRowAt indexPath:` using static cells either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138844/discussion-between-f-qi-and-frank-minyon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After our discussion, it's best for you to implement standard `UITableView` methods to achieve your goal and set `selectionStyle` to `.none`.  [Here](https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Using-UITableView) is a link to a tutorial, to help you with implementing the methods.